# Se pueden pasar parámetros en un un cron de cPanel

Tags: php

Qué tal compañeros   quisiera saber si es posible pasar  algún parámetro en el comando de cPanel a la hora de crear una tarea cronometra y si es así como se recibe en el php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun la documentación de php usando el array $argv

https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.argv.php

por ejemplo tendrias la linea en la terminal

**php /var/www/script.php valor1 valor2**

```php
echo $argv[0] //imprime el nombre del archivo (/var/www/script.php)
echo $argv[1] //imprime el primer parametro (valor1)
echo $argv[2] //imprime el segudno parametro (valor2)
//... asi sucesivamente
```